# Viewpager with Nestedscrollview and Recyclerview loading with jerk android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, nestedscrollview

I have used `ViewPager` with `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`. All is working fine expect while loading the screen the recycler view loads first and then view pager with jerk(not smoothly) and its not look good.

Right now I am implementing with design side not set any adapter for view pager.
I have not populated data not for view pager nor for recyclerview.

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<hammerapps.views.CustomNestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray_bg"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaRegular
                    android:id="@+id/txt_cat_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="EXPLORE"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_color"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_home_explore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaBold
                android:id="@+id/txt_cat1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="EXCLUSIVE"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_color"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/border_yellow"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_home_exclusive"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaBold
                android:id="@+id/txt_get_social"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="GET SOCIAL"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_color"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaBold
                android:id="@+id/txt_twicestyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="\@twicelifestyle \#twicelifestyle"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_home_get_social"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaRegular
                android:id="@+id/txt_view_gallery"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@color/blue_light_bg_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="VIEW GALLERY"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                />

            <hammerapps.views.TextViewKarlaRegular
                android:id="@+id/txt_upload_pic"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="UPLOAD YOUR PICTURE"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</hammerapps.views.CustomNestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Issue :**

[image]

Comment: post your java code. it's not enough for your question.

Comment: What do you want to see? I have already told that i haven't set any thing for view pager

Comment: If i m not wrong it happen when splash screen is gone,M i Right ?

Comment: Yes its a normal case. ! Its not affected by activity transition animation !

Comment: Have you try loading `ViewPager` ? it look like `ViewPager` loads after the `RecyclerView` set its data .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the answer with myself !!

I have implemented custom `NestedScrollView` and override this two methods and its working like a charm !

```
@Override
public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Request focus");

}

@Override
protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Request focus descendants");
    //return super.onRequestFocusInDescendants(direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    return false;
}
```